# How to find face neighbours in Maya?

Tags: python, maya, mel, face

I have a problem where I need to select faces that are next to one pre-selected face.

This may be done easily but the problem is that when I get a neighbour face I need to know in which direction it is facing.

So now I am able to select faces which are connected with an edge but I can't get the face that is for example left or right from the first selected face. I have tried multiple approaches but can't find the solution.

**I tried with:**

1. **pickWalk -** `cmds.pickWalk()`- problem with this is that it's behavior can't be predicted, since it walks the mesh from the camera perspective.
2. **polyInfo -** `cmds.polyInfo()`- this is a very useful function and closest to the answer. In this approach I try to extract edges from a face and then see which are neighbours to that face with `edgeToFace()`. This works well but doesn't solve my problem. To elaborate, when `polyInfo` returns faces that share edges, it doesn't return them in a way that I can always know that `edgesList[0]` (for example) is the edge that points left or right. Hence if I use this on different faces the resulting face may be facing in a different direction in each case.
3. **Hard way** with many conversions from vertex to edge then to face etc. But still again it's the same problem where I don't know which edge is the top or left one.
4. `conectedFaces()`method who i call on selected face and it returns faces which are connected to first face,but still it`s the same problem,i dont know which face is facing which way.

To be clear I'm not using a pre-selected list of faces and checking them, but I need to know the faces without knowing or keeping their names somewhere. Does someone know a way that works with selection of faces?

To elaborate my question I made an image to make it clear:

[image: example]

As you can see from the example if there is selected face I need to select any of pointed faces, but that must be exact face I want to select. Other methods select all neighbour faces, but I need method that I can say "select right" and will select right one from first selected face.

Comment: So not like a grow selection? What determines their "direction"? Their position?

Comment: i updated the question with image example for my problem so the question can be understood better.

Comment: What you need to think about is what criteria are you using to determine what is left/right/up/down. Unless your mesh is predetermined to have 4 edges and aligned in a common axis then you need to provide the definition of what "up" is. This problem is missing this key requirement to provide a useful answer.

Comment: yes every face needs to have 4 edges.i whana get it working at least that way.the position of the object in other hand can be anywere in scene so what i mean by "up" is you start from selected face and up is top of it.so it needs to be object oriented.to elaborate more:if i rotate the object and then the "up" face what i be getting is facing down its ok.point is to get some way to walk through the faces but that movement to not to be random.The therms i am using such as "up", "down" ... are meant to explain what face from selected face perspective i need to get and not in world coordinates.

Comment: Well you could get all adjacent faces from the one you're moving from, then get their center position. Then let's say you're moving "up", you can select the one that has the highest y position. Doing it this way would also mean that it doesn't necessarily need to be a quad since it always compares to what is adjacent. Could this be a solution?

Answer (score 1):

This is one solution that would be fairly consistent under the rule that up/down/left/right is aligned with the mesh's transformation (local space), though could be world space too.

The first thing I would do is build a face relative coordinate system for every mesh face using the average face vertex position, face normal, and world space Y axis of the mesh's transformation. This involves a little vector math, so I will use the API to make this easier. This first part will make a coordinate system for each face that we will store into lists for future querying. See below.

```
from maya import OpenMaya, cmds

meshTransform = 'polySphere'
meshShape = cmds.listRelatives(meshTransform, c=True)[0]

meshMatrix = cmds.xform(meshTransform, q=True, ws=True, matrix=True)
primaryUp = OpenMaya.MVector(*meshMatrix[4:7])
# have a secondary up vector for faces that are facing the same way as the original up
secondaryUp = OpenMaya.MVector(*meshMatrix[8:11])

sel = OpenMaya.MSelectionList()
sel.add(meshShape)

meshObj = OpenMaya.MObject()
sel.getDependNode(0, meshObj)

meshPolyIt = OpenMaya.MItMeshPolygon(meshObj)
faceNeighbors = []
faceCoordinates = []

while not meshPolyIt.isDone():

    normal = OpenMaya.MVector()
    meshPolyIt.getNormal(normal)

    # use the seconary up if the normal is facing the same direction as the object Y
    up = primaryUp if (1 - abs(primaryUp * normal)) > 0.001 else secondaryUp

    center = meshPolyIt.center()

    faceArray = OpenMaya.MIntArray()
    meshPolyIt.getConnectedFaces(faceArray)

    meshPolyIt.next()

    faceNeighbors.append([faceArray[i] for i in range(faceArray.length())])

    xAxis = up ^ normal
    yAxis = normal ^ xAxis

    matrixList = [xAxis.x, xAxis.y, xAxis.z, 0,
                  yAxis.x, yAxis.y, yAxis.z, 0,
                  normal.x, normal.y, normal.z, 0,
                  center.x, center.y, center.z, 1]

    faceMatrix = OpenMaya.MMatrix()
    OpenMaya.MScriptUtil.createMatrixFromList(matrixList, faceMatrix)

    faceCoordinates.append(faceMatrix)
```

These functions will look up and return which face is next to the one given in a particular direction (X and Y) relative to the face. This uses a dot product to see which face is more in that particular direction. This should work with any number of faces but it will only return one face that is in the most of that direction.

```
def getUpFace(faceIndex):
    return getDirectionalFace(faceIndex, OpenMaya.MVector(0,1,0))

def getDownFace(faceIndex):
    return getDirectionalFace(faceIndex, OpenMaya.MVector(0,-1,0))

def getRightFace(faceIndex):
    return getDirectionalFace(faceIndex, OpenMaya.MVector(1,0,0))

def getLeftFace(faceIndex):
    return getDirectionalFace(faceIndex, OpenMaya.MVector(-1,0,0))

def getDirectionalFace(faceIndex, axis):
    faceMatrix = faceCoordinates[faceIndex]

    closestDotProd = -1.0
    nextFace = -1

    for n in faceNeighbors[faceIndex]:
        nMatrix = faceCoordinates[n] * faceMatrix.inverse()
        nVector = OpenMaya.MVector(nMatrix(3,0), nMatrix(3,1), nMatrix(3,2))

        dp = nVector * axis

        if dp > closestDotProd:
            closestDotProd = dp
            nextFace = n

    return nextFace
```

So you would call it like this:

```
getUpFace(123)
```

With the number being the face index you want to get the face that is "up" from it.

Give this a try and see if it satisfies your needs.

Comment: i tested it and it works but its one problem.If i have faces that are in the same Y coordinates(example flat surface) it does not working.Its good idea but that`s why i didnt used coordinates before because i cant predict how object will be positioned in space or does faces will be facing some axis so i can check them.

Comment: to clarify more.if i make cube and start to go up from face it works well.when i get to the edge i get exacly the face wich is from other side of cube like i whant to get .But then when i call getUpFace on that returned face, is not continuing to follow the path but it gives other face (left or right).This was not pointed in the question as i didn`t anticipated it but still this solution works 100% for single face finding.

Comment: Yes, this will not work if the faces are facing directly up, you can catch these case when building the coordinate system and set a new up vector instead of Y. So it's possible to handle these corner cases. You would just get the dot product of the normal and the up vector and if it's withing a very small tolerance to -1 and 1, set the up to something else that you feel make sense, Z for instance. I'll update my answer to include this.

Answer (score 0):

[polyListComponentConversion](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2009help/CommandsPython/polyListComponentConversion.html)

```
import pprint
init_face = cmds.ls(sl=True)

#get edges
edges = cmds.polyListComponentConversion(init_face, ff=True, te=True)
#get neighbour faces
faces = cmds.polyListComponentConversion(edges, fe=True, tf=True, bo=True)
# show neighbour faces
cmds.select(faces)
# print face normal of each neighbour face
pprint.pprint(cmds.ployInfo(faces,fn=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of doing this is using Pymel's connectedFaces() on the MeshFace:

http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/pymel/generated/classes/pymel.core.general/pymel.core.general.MeshFace.html

```
import pymel.core as pm

sel = pm.ls(sl=True)[0]
pm.select(sel.connectedFaces())
```

Comment: as you can see in the question i alredy tried with connectedFaces() and its stated that it isn`t fixing the problem.